# Is there any difference while executing SWF in AWS , in normal AWS project and Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-swf

While executing the SWF in maven project getting the following error, can u please help me how to resolve the this error

ERROR  execute, Failure processing activity task with taskId=6, workflowGenerationId=MainWorkflowPCompress, activity={Name: Activity.DownloadFromS3,Version: 22.0}, activityInstanceId=1
com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.ActivityFailureException: **com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceRequest.copyPrivateRequestParameters()Ljava/util/Map;** : ["java.lang.NoSuchMethodError",{"cause":null,"stackTrace":[{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":"AmazonS3Client.java","lineNumber":3651,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"getObject","fileName":"AmazonS3Client.java","lineNumber":1160,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"getS3ObjectStream","fileName":"AmazonS3Client.java","lineNumber":1248,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client$3","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"retryableDownloadS3ObjectToFile","fileName":"ServiceUtils.java","lineNumber":382,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.s3.internal.ServiceUtils","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"getObject","fileName":"AmazonS3Client.java","lineNumber":1244,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"DownloadFromS3","fileName":"ActivityImpl.java","lineNumber":135,"className":"com.quantiphi.Pagination.Compress.ActivityImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke0","fileName":null,"lineNumber":-2,"className":"sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl","nativeMethod":true},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":null,"lineNumber":-1,"className":"sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":null,"lineNumber":-1,"className":"sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"invoke","fileName":null,"lineNumber":-1,"className":"java.lang.reflect.Method","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"execute","fileName":"POJOActivityImplementation.java","lineNumber":64,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.pojo.POJOActivityImplementation","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"execute","fileName":"ActivityImplementationBase.java","lineNumber":46,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.generic.ActivityImplementationBase","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"execute","fileName":"SynchronousActivityTaskPoller.java","lineNumber":196,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.SynchronousActivityTaskPoller","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"run","fileName":"ActivityTaskPoller.java","lineNumber":92,"className":"com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.ActivityTaskPoller$2","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"runWorker","fileName":null,"lineNumber":-1,"className":"java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"run","fileName":null,"lineNumber":-1,"className":"java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker","nativeMethod":false},{"methodName":"run","fileName":null,"lineNumber":-1,"className":"java.lang.Thread","nativeMethod":false}],"localizedMessage":"com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceRequest.copyPrivateRequestParameters()Ljava/util/Map;","message":"com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceRequest.copyPrivateRequestParameters()Ljava/util/Map;","suppressed":["[Ljava.lang.Throwable;",[]]}]
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.pojo.POJOActivityImplementation.throwActivityFailureException(POJOActivityImplementation.java:110)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.pojo.POJOActivityImplementation.execute(POJOActivityImplementation.java:67)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.generic.ActivityImplementationBase.execute(ActivityImplementationBase.java:46)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.SynchronousActivityTaskPoller.execute(SynchronousActivityTaskPoller.java:196)
    at com.amazonaws.services.simpleworkflow.flow.worker.ActivityTaskPoller$2.run(ActivityTaskPoller.java:92)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a moment to read the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. Simply pasting a stacktrace/error into the question body is not a good question. For the moment I will be voting to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError from method "invoke" of "AmazonS3Client.java" at "lineNumber":3651

So the exception is not related to the Simple Workflow but rather to S3 calling into some incompatible code. Make sure that all dependent libraries are of the correct version.

Comment: Thnks for reply, the same code is working the normal project, while converting the normal project to Maven project showing **com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceRequest.copyPrivateRequestParameters()Ljava/util/Map; ** this error , i dnt know y this error is coming, previously working maven project also showing the now above error, is there chance any setting problems in eclipse, ??

Comment: It looks like you Maven config pulls incompatible libraries into your application classpath. It is certainly not related to the SWF as exception is coming from S3 client code.